# Notification action icon didn't show

Tags: android, notifications, icons, action

I try to show a notification in Android, and use the code from [this Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).
In some source people said that the icon should be totally white and some source said I should use *.png* instead of *vector*.

I try all of this ways but no one didn't help me.

I try this code:

```
Notification newMessageNotification =
    new Notification.Builder(mContext)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.content))
            .addAction(action))
            .build();
```

Comment: paste your code

Comment: it was not about my code @NileshRathod

Comment: Your icon should be .png and white color

Comment: I do all of this solution @Mohammadnabil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after search about 1 hour in all the question with this topic finally I find out it's because of my android version! 
look at the image below. In Api level 24 an above, there is no icon in design!!

[image: Android N notification screenshot]

Comment: yes,your android version must be higher than 19 for supporting notification icon.

Answer (score 1):

With Nougat they have changed design of Notification icons

> https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/notifications-in-android-n.html

You’ll note that the icons are not present in the new notifications; instead more room is provided for the labels themselves in the constrained space of the notification shade. However, the notification action icons are still required and continue to be used on older versions of Android and on devices such as Android Wear.

Answer (score 0):

**Notification icons must be entirely white**

If you want to support Lollipop Material Icons then make transparent icons for **Lollipop and above version**. Please refer following https://design.google.com/icons/

Comment: I try this, but in Api 24 and above there is no icon even in design, except media play mode.

Comment: Use setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification_icon).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: my problem is about action icon. small and big icon are about main notification

Comment: Are you trying it this way?
NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Click", pendingIntent).build();

Comment: Notification newMessageNotification =
        new Notification.Builder(mContext)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.content))
                .addAction(action))
                .build();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146718/discussion-between-ashkan-and-nancy-y).