# Icons in Action Button of Notification are not visible

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to create a notification for a music player app. I want to add three Action button on notification for actions previous, Play/pause, next. For actions I want to add Icons from drawable(R.drawable.ic_pervious, R.drawable.ic_pause and R.drawable.ic_next). After a study I used below code but icons are not visible to me.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Apna time ayega")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) //intent
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pervious, "", pendingPrevIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "", pendingPlayIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "", pendingNextIntent)
                .build();
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        startForeground(1, notification);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notification action icon didn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558501/notification-action-icon-didnt-show)

Answer (score 0):

From android nougat onwards, notification action icons are not present in notifications. However, notifications action icons are required and they are shown in older versions of android and Android wear.

Source - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/notifications-in-android-n.html

Comment: It is not about notification icon. I asked for Action Button icon. I have android Q. One music player application is showing Action button icon in notification in android Q. So what i need to do same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558501/notification-action-icon-didnt-show

Comment: Music players use MediaStyle notifications. MediaStyle notifications are typically used by bound and started services that allow audio playback to occur in the background